# Does a new instance of Android SQLiteOpenHelper create a new database in the app directory?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a created a database helper class in android and my concern is that every time I create a new instance of the Helper class, does android system create a new database that overwrites all the previous data?

```
public class UserHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user.db";

    public UserHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        final String SQL_CREATE_USER_PROFILE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + UserProfileEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " (" +
                UserProfileEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_PHONE + " INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CHILD_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CHILD_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CHILD_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " UNIQUE ( " + UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_PHONE + ", " +
                UserProfileEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_EMAIL + " ) ON CONFLICT IGNORE " +
                ");";

        final String SQL_CREATE_ALL_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + AllActivitiesEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " ( " +
                AllActivitiesEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                AllActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ACTIVITY_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                AllActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MIN_AGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL );";

        final String SQL_CREATE_USER_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                UserActivitiesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                UserActivitiesEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                UserActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                UserActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ACTIVITY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +

                //Setting up COLUMN_USER_ID as a foreign key to UserProfileTable
                " FOREIGN KEY ( " + UserActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ID + " ) REFERENCES " +
                UserProfileEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + UserProfileEntry._ID + " ), " +

                //Setting up COLUMN_USER_ACTIVITY_ID as a foreign key to AllActivitiesTable
                " FOREIGN KEY ( " + UserActivitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ACTIVITY_ID +
                " ) REFERENCES " + AllActivitiesEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " ( " + AllActivitiesEntry._ID + " ) );";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_PROFILE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ALL_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);
    }

    public static boolean checkDatabaseExists(Context context, String databaseName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java). It's quite short.

Answer (score 2):

It the database does not exist, it will create one, with the version number specified in your constructor. Android will then call you onCreate() method to create the tables.

If the database does exist, then onUpgrade() will be called with the old and new version numbers. This allows you to add missing tables for users who are on an older version of your app, and are upgrading to a newer version.